# Deploying microcks on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to install microcks on a GKE autopilot cluster, but getting issues with keycloak healthchecks:

```
Readiness probe failed: Get "http://10.34.128.130:8080/health/ready": dial tcp 10.34.128.130:8080: connect: connection refused
```

The docs mention:

> When using Minikube, depending on what you’ve already deployed, the default configuration may be little bit slow and induce timeout on readiness probes. We usually setup the following configuration for successful deployments:

```
minikube config set cpus 4
minikube config set memory 6144
minikube delete
minikube start
```

Has anyone tried installing microcks on a GKE cluster and have instructions?

```
helm repo add microcks https://microcks.io/helm

kubectl create namespace microcks

helm install microcks microcks/microcks --version 1.1.0 --namespace microcks
```

I was expecting the keycloak service to be ready after some time.

Comment: above error is with keyclock or with the micros ? readiness failing check the logs of the pod